# Does raising an object fastly gives more potential energy than if it were raised to the same height slowly?

Tags: forces, work, potential-energy, definition

If we raise an object fastly we apply more force so  more work is done and eventually potential energy stored by object should be larger than that if it were raised slowly to the same height. But it does not happen, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient prior research.

Comment: It does not happen because the definition of potential energy is that the necessary work to get from one point to another only depends on the location of the two points, but not on how one gets from one to the other.

Comment: And if you use more force you then have to use force again to stop it.

Comment: How do you know "it does not happen"?

Answer (score 1):

In a conservative force field such as gravity, change in potential energy of an object depends only on its initial and final position. Any extra work you do on top of increase in potential energy of the object in raising it, is simply wasted away into heat (ultimately).

Answer (score 1):

The potential energy of an object only depends on the height of the object. What happens when the object is raised quickly is that it also gains kinetic energy. So the total energy (potential + kinetic) is larger, but the potential energy is the same because it was raised to the same height.

Answer (score -1):

Because if you push it up quickly, you also need to *pull* on it more strongly at the top of its trajectory to slow it back to rest again, removing the benefit of all the extra energy you put into it.

Comment: This is not correct, the potential energy only depends on difference in height as pointed out in other answers/comments. The work done is different but that is not the same as the potential energy.

Comment: @porphyrin Of the course the potential energy is the same in both cases - I was trying to give an intuitive explanation off *why* you don't give the object more potential energy by raising it quickly.  And the work done is also the same in both cases, because the net work done is just the change in total energy.

Comment: I was thinking also about the work you would have to do , raising it infinitesimally slowly vs. really going for it, as it were.

Comment: @porphyrin I was getting at the same thing that Bob Bee was in his comment to the OP.